How to have a sbt module for standardized test utility that uses util module
In a fairly large project (~50 submodules), I want to create a "myspec" module that will be the standard way to create test in this project.
To be successful, this module need to help with our common ground (using our own value classes, with matchers for our own helpers)
So, the myspec / Compile configuration needs to depends on the util / Compile scope (in order to create matchers).
What I tried can be reduced to:

a sbt project

with two modules: spec and util

util/src/main/com/example/Constants.scala
package com.example

object Constants {
  val Foobar = "From util/Compile/Constants"
}

for simulating the definition of our primitives or our helpers

spec/src/main/com/example/spec/BaseSpec.scala:
package com.example.spec

trait BaseSpec {
  def fromBase: String = s"base include ${com.example.Constants.Foobar}"
}

for simulating the definition of our common ground for the way we create tests and our custom matchers

util/src/test/com/example/ConstantSpec.scala file
package com.example

object ConstantSpec extends App with com.example.spec.BaseSpec {
  println(s"test run: ${fromBase}")
}



Naturally, my first attempt with build.sbt was:
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .dependsOn(spec % Test)

lazy val spec = (project in file("spec"))
  .dependsOn(util)

And I thought that will work because even if util / Test depends on spec / Compile and spec / Compile depends on util / Compile, there should not have a cyclic dependencies.
But the instantiation of the graph itself was containing cyclic call (to define util project, you need to instantiate the spec project, and for spec project you need an instance of util)
So, I discovered the usage of LocalProject to bypass such cycle:
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .dependsOn(LocalProject("spec") % Test)

lazy val spec = (project in file("spec"))
  .dependsOn(util)

But when using dependsOn the project itself depends on another project. and the sbt graph contains cyclic references.
So I needed to overcome that by telling explicitly that I wanted util's results in the classpath of spec / Compile. I discovered "exportedProducts" (thanks to this post: Using a common test utility file for projects built in SBT) :
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .dependsOn(spec % Test)

lazy val spec = (project in file("spec"))
  .settings(
    Compile / managedClasspath ++= (LocalProject("util") / Compile / exportedProducts).value
  )

And now, my sample project is working: sbt "util/Test/run" compile and run smoothly.
(I will have to manage dependencies of spec, but that will be another story, I guess)
But (yes, there is a "but" otherwise I won't post here, obviously), now IntelliJ idea is not happy with that. The IDE doesn't understand that BaseSpec (in spec module) can import Constants (from util module) even if sbt is fine with it.
How to tell IntelliJ idea about that without modifying manually the project structure each time I'll reimport the sbt definition?

Sounds quite complicated TBH. Why not have 3 modules "util" (no test), "spec" depends on "util", "util-test" depends on "util" and "spec"? No cyclic dependencies. Simple setup.

Because "util-test" feel messy, and we still do have test, integration-test and we even added performance-test and benchmark configurations. Without mentioning that some module have configuration (aka scope) for source generation etc. If we need a top module for each, it may be difficult to name them and not very clean to have separate folders as well

Just move spec/src/main to util/src/test, get rid of spec module, and make your other modules depend on util.

@Dima And I will need to add util % "compile->compile;test->test" everywhere? Not fancy as well

@Isammoc no, you should just add util as a project dependency to each sub-project. That doesn't seem surprising for a common dependency.  What people often do is write a function in sbt that adds common configuration to every project so that they don't have to replicate it everywhere.

@Dima I'm not sure I was clear that "spec" module contains the core definition for every spec (only accessible in Test scope for other projects). Say we'll have to depends on spec % Test instead of scalatest

@Isammoc sure. So, you just say lazy val foo = project.in(file("foo")).dependsOn('util') I don't see the problem. Or you can extract this (and other common configs) into a function and just do val foo = myProject('foo')

In your example, foo/src/main/scala/foo/Foo.scala may import classes from util/src/main/scala/**, but foo/src/test/scala/foo/FooSpec.scala cannot import what you suggest to put into util/src/test (originally, what I currently have in spec/src/main).

@Isammoc no, if foo depends on util, then classes in foo/main can use util/main, and classes in foo/test can use both util/main and util/test

Weird, I was pretty sure that we should have to add the "compile->compile,test->test" modifier... Let me try that
